Realm Database has an unsupported version (24) and cannot be upgraded, No Schema selected
I'm trying to use realm studio to open a realm database file and when trying to I am getting the error message "Database has an unsupported version (24) and cannot be upgraded, No Schema selected."  Current Configuration, xcode is version 15.3, Realm installed using swift package manager Realm Master version (2f0274f) and RealmDatabase 14.5.0, and Realm Studio is version 14.1.2.
Everything appears to work correctly via Xcode and when I run the app.  I and add, update, and delete items from the realm database without issue or error. I have deleted the realm db files directly from finder and let them rebuild and everything via Xcode runs correctly.  However, same thing happens when I try and open the file via realm studio.  No matter what I do I can't open the realm file via realm studio.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

TL/DR; see the Realm Studio note at the bottom:
The underlying database in the Realm file you are attempting to work with is not compatible with the SDK & the version of Realm Studio.

If your database was created with pre - v5.0.0 SDK, you will need to use SDK 10.48.0, and allow it to update the underlying database - which is automatic thing but any later SDK will not work.

Once that's done, the current Realm Studio and Realm SDK can read the file so you can move on to a later SDK and you'll be all set.

If your database was created with something newer, then you will need to install the latest SDK and more importantly, the latest Realm Studio, which can be used to read v24 databases

Edit:
If you're upgrading an old Realm ensure you using the correct versions: In XCode, in the Project Navigator on the left, ensure the Realm package is Realm is 10.48.0 and Realm Database is 13.26.0.
When Adding packages be sure to select Dependency Rule: Exact Version and set it to 10.48.0
- Realm Studio Note
Also, Realm Studio 15 was recently released which may also resolve the issue for you. The notes state

Added support for reading / writing Realm files using Realm file
format v24, supporting realm-js v12.7.0, realm-dart v2.0.0 and
realm-swift v10.49.0. When opening a file which is using an older
format, you will get prompted to upgrade (and optionally backup) the
Realm file. NOTE: Once the file has been upgraded, there is no way to
downgrade it again and it can only be used by the SDKs that support
Realm file format v24.

Realm Studio Releases can be found here so grab the latest version and see if that helps.

I have deleted the database all together and let it completely rebuild and date and time stamp suggest such.  It still produces the same error message. The database and the original databases were built with version 10 and greater.

@brandonaho Yeah, that happens, and there could be a number of reasons. Based on the additional info though, it sounds like you need to run Realm Studio 15, which will read the Realm file format v24 (see the link in my answer) as well as update older Realm files to the newer SDK's if necessary. Keeping in mind if you do that, your Packages should be Realm Swift 10.49.0 or higher. You can see the versions in XCode, Project Navigator under dependencies which should be showing Realm 10.49.1 and Realm Database 14.4.1 or higher.

That's exactly what mongoDB came back with.  I wasn't aware that they released version 15.  https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases here is the link for anyone that may get this error message in the future.

@brandonaho Cool! I think that will fix it. I had included that link in my answer as well. Let us know if it doesn't fix it.
